# iterating anonymous inner classes java

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public void Or(BinaryMap source, RectangleC area, Point at) { 
  Combine(source, area, at, new CombineFunction() { 
   @Override
   public void combine(int[] target, int[] srcVector) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < target.length; ++i) 
     target[i] |= srcVector[i]; 
   } 
  });  
 }
```

I'm having trouble understanding how is the interface `CombineFunction` implementation works and the parameters passed to the function combine are saved where?

Note:

The code is not mine it is a reference from here 
https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=SecugenPlugin-master/src/sourceafis/simple/Fingerprint.java#

I am only trying to understand how it works.

The code:

```
 interface CombineFunction { 
  void combine(int[] target, int[] source); 
 }

 void Combine(final BinaryMap source, final RectangleC area, final Point at, 
   final CombineFunction function) { 
  final int shift = (area.X & WordMask) - (at.X & WordMask); 
  int vectorSize = (area.Width >> WordShift) + 2; 
  CombineLocals combineLocals = new CombineLocals(); 
  combineLocals.Vector = new int[vectorSize]; 
  combineLocals.SrcVector = new int[vectorSize]; 
  ParallelForDelegate<CombineLocals> delegate = new ParallelForDelegate<CombineLocals>() { 
   @Override 
   public CombineLocals delegate(int y, CombineLocals locals) { 
    LoadLine(locals.Vector, new Point(at.X, at.Y + y), area.Width); 
    source.LoadLine(locals.SrcVector, 
      new Point(area.X, area.Y + y), area.Width); 
    if (shift >= 0) 
     ShiftLeft(locals.SrcVector, shift); 
    else 
     ShiftRight(locals.SrcVector, -shift); 
    function.combine(locals.Vector, locals.SrcVector); 
    SaveLine(locals.Vector, new Point(at.X, at.Y + y), area.Width); 
    return locals; 
   } 

   @Override 
   public CombineLocals combineResults(CombineLocals result1, 
     CombineLocals result2) { 
    return null; 
   } 
  }; 

 Parallel.For(0, area.Height, delegate, combineLocals); 
 }
```

Comment: This isn't valid syntax. Do you mean `@Override public void combine`?

Comment: yes i do mean that

Comment: "even though the code works fine." This simply doesn't compile. If you think it runs fine, you're running an earlier version.

Comment: Oh. i'm sorry for that

Comment: Fix the code please, its incorrect.

Comment: is `Combine` a method?

Comment: it is a method.

Comment: Of what? Note that method names shall not begin with an upper case letter, only constructors shall be named like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Combine` is a method with the following signature:

```
private void Combine(BinaryMap bm, RectangleC rc, Point p, CombineFunction cf)
```

NOTE: As Lutz Horn pointed out in his comment, method names should start with a lower case letter, so it should be `combine`

**Syntax**

Writing

```
public void Or(BinaryMap source, RectangleC area, Point at) {
  Combine(source, area, at, new CombineFunction() {
    @Override
    public void combine(int[] target, int[] srcVector) {
      for (int i = 0; i < target.length; ++i)
        target[i] |= srcVector[i];
    }
  });
}
```

is the same as writing

```
class MyCombineFunction implements CombineFunction {

  @Override
  public void combine(int[] target, int[] srcVector) {
    for (int i = 0; i < target.length; ++i)
      target[i] |= srcVector[i];
  }

}
```

and then use this class this way:

```
public void Or(BinaryMap source, RectangleC area, Point at) {
    Combine(source, area, at, new MyCombineFunction());
}
```

It is just a shortcut so you don't have to declare a new class.

**How it is used inside the Combine method**

Then the `Combine` method uses the custom implementation of `MyCombineFunction` that you passed to it. 
It would be calling its `combine` method somehow during its execution, something like this:

```
private void Combine(BinaryMap bm, RectangleC rc, Point p, CombineFunction cf) {

    int[] target = ...;
    int[] src = ...
    cf.combine(target, source); // this will use the implementation you wrote when overriding the combine method
}
```

Comment: Where are the target and srcVector are saved? what is the use of declaring the arrays inside the function ?

Comment: we need to see the code of the `combine` method to know what it does with the `CombineFunction` implementation you are passing to it.

Comment: I edited it to include the method and the interface.

Comment: @AMA I added to my answer to explain how Combine can use the CombineFunction object

Comment: Thanks for the help i understood the idea.

Comment: @Welcome, upvote and accept the answer if it solves your issue!